# Php sprintf: combine 2 variables values (string) in %s

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, get, woocommerce

With WooCommerce, I would like the the value of `$gclid` variable to be combined in the `href="%s"` below. I edited it by placing the `$gclid` after the `$product->add_to_cart_url()`, but that doesn't work.

```
global $product;
$gclid=$_GET['gclid']; //Read gclid and store it in $gclid

echo apply_filters(
    'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf(
         '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
         esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url().$gclid ),
         esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
         esc_attr( $product->id ),
         esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
         esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
         esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
    $product
);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Any errors? What I see is that you have wrong syntax: `apply_filters(X, sprintf(X, esc_url(X)`. Where are two closing brackets?

Comment: `code`global $product;
$gclid=$_GET['gclid']; //Read gclid and store it in $gclid
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
 sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
  esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url().$gclid ),
  esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
  esc_attr( $product->id ),
  esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
  esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
  esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
 ),
$product );

Comment: No errors, but not working. I am just trying to make the link href="%s" include $gclid. Its a link and I am pulling the gclid from the url and placing it at the end of the link. This is the entire code, I didnt give the whole code before to try to shorten it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Your question is a little bit unclear**
You should specify first that you want to edit the **`loop/add-to-cart.php`** WooCommerce template that displays **add-to-cart button** on shop and archives WooCommerce pages.

As it set a GET Url in the **`href`** **`<a>`** tag like for example:

```js
http://www.myshop.com/shop/?add-to-cart=208
```

To make it work you will need to add something like:

```js
http://www.myshop.com/shop/?add-to-cart=208&gclid=601
```

This will work adding **`&`** + **`gclid=`** + the value of **`gclid`** (here for example **`601`**)…

So the code below **will work perfectly** (see it in action on **[this test server](http://www.cbleu.net/sites/tie/shop/)**):

```
<?php
/**
 * Loop Add to Cart
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/add-to-cart.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

// Just for testing (replace after with $gclid=$_GET['gclid'];)
$gclid = '&gclid=120';
// $gclid=$_GET['gclid'];

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url().$gclid ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );

// Checking that you get 'gclid' value (just for test)
// (will display normally the 'gclid' value after the button add-to-cart)
echo '<p>gclid value: '. $_GET['gclid'] .</p>;
```

> The problem is certainly coming from your **`$gclid=$_GET['gclid'];`**. 
> **You have to be sure that you are getting the value of `'gclid'`**.
>
> Once you are sure you are getting **`'gclid'`** value, you should change it a little bit, this way:
>
> ```
>  $gclid= '&gclid=' . $_GET['gclid'];
> ```

This should work…

Comment: Very weird situation. When you hover over the link, it doesnt show the gclid and when you click it, it doesnt place the gclid in the link. However, if you CTRL+U to see the page code, the link actually has the gclid. Any idea how the page code can have the correct info, but what's displayed and works doesnt? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I saw that. I added the same code to mine and it doesn't work on mine. Maybe it's the template?  A plugin? What do you suggest?